# Saving R script in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I am getting this warning while saving R script in Rstudio and I am not able to save and retrieve the R script. Need help in this.
Thanks.

[image: This is the popup while saving the script]

Comment: As the dialog says, you’re providing the wrong file extension when saving the file.

Comment: I added a  .R extension

Comment: We can't really help much, but my guess: you previously saved it or renamed it (at some other time) in windows' file explorer as `"something.R"`, and windows thinks it knows better (because you have not told it to *not* "hide extensions of known file types") so windows silently added `.txt` to the filename. Suggestion: go to windows file explorer (`Win-E`), go to *View > Options > Change folder and search options* (`Alt-V Y O`), go to the *View* sub-tab, ensure *"Hide extensions for known file types"* is deselected. Now rename in file explorer to `"something.R"`.

Comment: I did this process but still if I create a new project and new script still I am getting the same error.

Comment: Don't add an extension. Rstudio by default adds an .R extension. so if you want to name your script foo.R, just type foo and hit enter

Comment: Have the same error even without an extension.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem both when adding extension .R and when not, but it only appeared when trying to save to my company's remote file system, when instead saving locally it worked just fine (my R studio and R installations are also locally), maybe something similar happens on your system?

Answer (score 1):

This error can arise if you have dot in the name of your script. Since dot specifies extension, it will confuse file explorer as to to the type of the file. Make sure that script name does not contain `.`.